# getting JSON data from balanced-payments using Node.js lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, balanced-payments

Playing around with Balanced-Payments API Trying to wrap my head around the way their Node.js lib is constructed. I am a relative newcomer to JS so I am still tripping over promises.

When using code straight from their example for listing customers http://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/api/customers/#list-all-customers
I am kind of at a loss looking at their syntax for **balanced.marketplace.customers**

It's not a function that returns a value and when I tried `console.log(balanced.marketplace.customers)`I get `{ [Function: act] _promised_something: 'customers' }` I've been racking my brains as to how to use this approach as a standard PROMISE.then(something) approach doesn't seem to make sense here.

Thanks in advance for any help on this usage of promises.

Comment: I never used their api but I think it returns a promise so maybe `balanced.marketplace.customers().then(function(data) { console.log(data); });` Just guessing here.

Comment: @moogs That's exactly what I thought should happen but this doesn't produce ANY output. + it doesn't seem to be a function and almost looks like (pardon C terminology) a pointer to a function. I am just really confused by the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is:

```
balanced.marketplace.customers.then(function(data){ 
  console.log(data); 
});
```

However, if you would like to pretty print out the json object that's returned you'll need to add a method such as:

```
function print(obj) {
    console.log('string' === typeof obj ? obj : JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
}
```

This would replace the console.log in the first code example.

Comment: thnx. starting to sync in :)